# Download Image from Http Get Response

Tags: java, rest

I'm using Postman to test an api link and my response is an image as shown below :

[image]

I have written some http get code like this to call api:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode("kermit:kermit".getBytes());       
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances/" +processInstanceId +"/diagram");
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedBytes)

request.addHeader("content-type", "image/png");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Now I want to download that image to a specific path in my hard drive. I searched some post in here but it's not my expected result.
Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't add a byte array to a String:

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedBytes);
```

You could try something like this:

```
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8"));
```

You'll have to catch or throw the `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Second, you shouldn't set the `content-type` header. You probably meant to use the `Accept` header.

Once you have the response, you can save the contents of the `OutputStream` to a file or do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/process-instances/" +processInstanceId +"/diagram");

request.addHeader("content-type", "image/png");
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        try (FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("download-image.png"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            entity.writeTo(outstream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is myFile variable? a File?

Comment: Where I can find the file saved?

Comment: You can save this file in any place in your disk. For example /tmp/ or c:/tmp. 
So you need to give the full path such as new File("/tmp/download-image.png")

Comment: ok I found it, but I can't open image file. It's say:"Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large".

Comment: You may try to add StandardCharsets.UTF_8. But I think from your url (https://m.imgur.com/c7caT2O)) is a html web not image. If you need img try this url https://i.imgur.com/c7caT2O.png.

Comment: right, I understood, my link return a html with image inside. How should I do now? Sorry I'm quite new to this so I really don't know how to fix.

Comment: The question is what you need ? If you want download the html from (m.imgur.com/c7caT2O)  , you should save file as download.html. If you want to download png from (i.imgur.com/c7caT2O.png), you should save as download.png